# Add Google search field to website that searches in the address bar

Tags: google-chrome, google-search, address-bar

I have created a page to use as a 'homepage' when opening a new tab in Chrome, rather than the default Chrome 'New tab page'. I have used the extension 'New Tab Redirect' to display this page when I open a new tab.

I'd like to add a Google search field to this page that, when the user starts typing, it transfers to the browser address bar (like Google does on Chrome) - to allow either a Google search or to enter a URL.

I have looked around for a solution to this but haven't had any luck. Any ideas how this could be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Here it is explained pretty well:

http://www.brenkoweb.com/articles/development/designing-principles/how-to-add-a-search-field-to-your-website.php